# Wrap content in a layout when there's a ListView inside

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Here's my layout, I have a LinearLayout with two RelativeLayouts. One is full of TextViews, and the other has a ListView. Right now, I'm setting the height manually, what I want to do is to let the RelativeLayout with the TextViews determine the height. But if I use Wrap Content, the ListView wants to be as large as the screen. How can I achieve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/product_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.71"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:background="@drawable/product_info_top_border">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_info_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@string/product_info_name"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_info_shop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="@string/footer_shop"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_info_name"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/product_info_name"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/product_info_name"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_info_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="@string/product_info_description"
                android:maxLines="6"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_info_shop"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/product_info_shop"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/product_info_shop"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_info_reference"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="@string/product_info_reference"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_info_description"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/product_info_description"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/product_info_description" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_info_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@string/product_info_price"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/product_price_footer_relief"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/product_info_description"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/product_info_description"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.29"
            android:alpha="0.85"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_list_left_border">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/product_info_list_colors"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="20dp">

            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>
```

**EDIT**: I want to get rid of this:

```
android:layout_height="275dp"
```

So the height is determined by the RelativeLayouts full of TextViews (and not the ListView)

**EDIT2**: Code updated

Comment: please show screenshot what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use weights like this:

Wrapper element has: 
android:layout_hight="wrap_content"

First Element has:
android:layout_hight="wrap_content"

Second element has:
android:layout_height="match_parent"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/product_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.71"
                android:alpha="0.85"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_info_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="product_info_name"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_info_name1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="product_info_name"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_info_name2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="product_info_name"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_info_name3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="product_info_name"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.29"
                android:alpha="0.85"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/product_info_list_colors"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:dividerHeight="20dp">

                </ListView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean height instead of width?

Comment: Here you go, I re-posted

Comment: That didn't work for me, it takes all the screen with this approach

Comment: This is what you wanted(image), isn't it?

Comment: Yes! I don't how this is not working for me, can you post your code please?

Comment: Sorry, failed to update the code, should work now. my apologies.

Comment: Nothing, still doesn't work for me, I updated my original post with the code. Cant' see what's wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103238/discussion-between-monkeyfish-and-cuoka).

Comment: Did you find the problem?